# Vertically-scrolling overflow div in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm trying to get a div to scroll vertically through a number of li elements in my Wordpress install - I'm a serious amateur when it comes to jQuery / javascript, but after reading through forums on here all day long, I figured I'd check and see if someone with some experience could help me.

I've found a lot of great solutions, but every one of them seems to conflicting with another instance of jQuery or javascript or something.

Ideally, I'd like something that could scroll on hover, but I would settle for buttons, or even just a simple hide of the ugly scroll bar.

The page I'm working on is here: http://ryanlinstrom.com/sandbox/vimeo-test/

I'm using the following script on the page - if there's any way to integrate so that my #thumbs div can scroll without the addition of another script, that'd be wonderful.

```
        var apiEndpoint = 'http://vimeo.com/api/v2/';
    var oEmbedEndpoint = 'http://vimeo.com/api/oembed.json'
    var oEmbedCallback = 'switchVideo';
    var videosCallback = 'setupGallery';
    var vimeoUsername = 'user677763';

    // Get the user's videos
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.getScript(apiEndpoint + vimeoUsername + '/videos.json?callback=' + videosCallback);
    });

    function getVideo(url) {
        $.getScript(oEmbedEndpoint + '?url=' + url + '&width=780&height=435&callback=' + oEmbedCallback);
    }

    function setupGallery(videos) {

        // Sets the video title
        $('#stats h2').text(videos[0].title);

        // Load the first video
        getVideo(videos[0].url);


        // Add the videos to the gallery
        for (var i = 0; i < videos.length; i++) {
            var html = '<li><a href="' + videos[i].url + '" name="'+ videos[i].title +'"><img src="' + videos[i].thumbnail_medium + '" class="thumb" />';
            html += '</a><p>' + videos[i].title + '</p></li>';
            $('#thumbs ul').append(html);
        }


        // Switch to the video when a thumbnail is clicked
        $('#thumbs a').click(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            getVideo(this.href);
            $('#stats h2').detach();
            var title = $(this).attr("name");
            $('#stats').append('<h2></h2>');
            $("#stats h2").text(title);

            return false;
        });

    }

    function switchVideo(video) {
        $('#embed').html(unescape(video.html));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using two overlaying invisible divs (one at the top, one at the bottom).

Then doing something like:

```
$(".top-scroll").bind("mouseover", function(){
    $(".wrapping-div").animate({scrollTop: -= 5}, 100)
});

$(".bottom-scroll").bind("mouseover", function(){
    $(".wrapping-div").animate({scrollTop: += 5}, 100);
});
```

And then, of course, adding `overflow:hidden` to your css to remove the scrollbar.